# How can we access files from FTP folder in java web application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

What am i doing is uploading some images from client side on to FTP server. I am using FTP client and commons-net.jar to upload the images. I want these images in my Server side application. So plz help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Deleted my previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your server side app needs to "read-in" the image. So in your server app at some point you have to read the image from a file in the FTP folder, where the client has uploaded ...

```
Image image = null;
try {
    File file = new File("/home/user/ftp/image.jpg");
    image = ImageIO.read(file);
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Anyway, if you running a java web server your clients may upload the image directly with a http PUT request, without going thru FTP.

Comment: This is closer to what you want to do. The String inside the

    new File()

call should point to the folder where you upload the files to.